# SAS trying to get the difference in days from orderdate to shipdate

Tags: date, sas, days

I'm using adventureworks dataset.

Looking for methods to calculate on average how long in days does it take ADW to deliver products between the order date and shipment date.

format sas date9.

e.g.:

```
orderdate              shipdate
01JUL2005:00:00:00    08JUL2005:00:00:00
```

Comment: Please show what code you have tried, and describe any error messages you receive or describe why you are unhappy with the results. It also might help to  show a few sample records.

Comment: data productdate;
 set productdate;
 format= orderdate shipdate date9.;
productdelivery=orderdate-shipdate;
run; ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

72         productdelivery=orderdate-shipdate;
73         run;

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that might help. The SAS function [`intck()`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212868.htm) is very useful!

```
/* Generate a dataset as described. */
    data have;
        do id=1 to 10000;
            orderdate = today()-(ceil(ranuni(id)*1000));
            shipdate = orderdate + ceil(ranuni(id)*10);
            output;
        end;
        format orderdate shipdate date9.;
    run;

/* Use intck() to count the number of days or weekdays between order and delivery dates */
    data want;
        set have;
        weekdays_passed = intck('weekday7w',orderdate,shipdate);
        abs_days_passed = intck('day',orderdate,shipdate);
    run;

/* Two ways to obtain average delivery time in days. */
/*1*/
    proc univariate data=want;
        var weekdays_passed
            abs_days_passed;
    run;
/*2*/
    proc sql;
        select avg(weekdays_passed) as avg_weekdays_passed,
               avg(abs_days_passed) as avg_abs_days_passed
        from want;
    quit;
```